# Mule - Hive Connection Issue

Tags: hive, mule

While trying to connect to hive from mule (studio) using database connector (mule version 3.9.0) I am getting below error. In build path I have added "hive-jdbc-3.1.0.3.0.0.0-1634-standalone.jar"

I am able to connect to Hive through Dbeaver without issues.

Can someone help? My configuration is

```
jdbc:hive2://host:port/Default;user=******;password=******
```

Full Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory does not implement the requested interface org.apache.hive.org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory does not implement the requested interface org.apache.hive.org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory
    at org.apache.hive.org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:285)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<clinit>(HiveConnection.java:121)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
    at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource.getConnection(StandardDataSource.java:203)
    at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource.getConnection(StandardDataSource.java:144)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.SimpleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SimpleConnectionFactory.java:43)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.create(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:23)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.createDataSourceConnection(TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.java:93)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.createConnection(TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.java:53)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.database.GenericDbConfig.test(GenericDbConfig.java:80)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.database.AbstractDbConfigResolver.test(AbstractDbConfigResolver.java:30)
    at org.mule.tooling.metadata.api.utils.ConnectionTester.internalTestConnection(ConnectionTester.java:88)
    at org.mule.tooling.metadata.api.utils.ConnectionTester.testConnectionFor(ConnectionTester.java:113)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction$1$1$1$1.call(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:68)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction$1$1$1$1.call(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:1)
    at org.mule.tooling.utils.SilentRunner.run(SilentRunner.java:25)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.StudioDesignContextRunner.runSilentWithMuleProject(StudioDesignContextRunner.java:17)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.StudioDesignContextRunner.runSilentWithMuleProject(StudioDesignContextRunner.java:37)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction$1$1$1.run(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:65)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

  java.lang.Throwable: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory does not implement the requested interface org.apache.hive.org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory
    at org.apache.hive.org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:285)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<clinit>(HiveConnection.java:121)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
    at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource.getConnection(StandardDataSource.java:203)
    at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource.getConnection(StandardDataSource.java:144)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.SimpleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SimpleConnectionFactory.java:43)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.create(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:23)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.createDataSourceConnection(TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.java:93)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.createConnection(TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.java:53)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.database.GenericDbConfig.test(GenericDbConfig.java:80)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.database.AbstractDbConfigResolver.test(AbstractDbConfigResolver.java:30)
    at org.mule.tooling.metadata.api.utils.ConnectionTester.internalTestConnection(ConnectionTester.java:88)
    at org.mule.tooling.metadata.api.utils.ConnectionTester.testConnectionFor(ConnectionTester.java:113)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction$1$1$1$1.call(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:68)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction$1$1$1$1.call(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:1)
    at org.mule.tooling.utils.SilentRunner.run(SilentRunner.java:25)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.StudioDesignContextRunner.runSilentWithMuleProject(StudioDesignContextRunner.java:17)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.StudioDesignContextRunner.runSilentWithMuleProject(StudioDesignContextRunner.java:37)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction$1$1$1.run(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:65)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  
    at org.mule.tooling.metadata.utils.MetadataUtils.showErrorMessage(MetadataUtils.java:373)
    at org.mule.tooling.metadata.utils.MetadataUtils.showTestConnectionErrorMessage(MetadataUtils.java:338)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.displayResultMessage(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:110)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.run(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:98)
    at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.dialog.GlobalElementDialog$1.widgetSelected(GlobalElementDialog.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.mule.tooling.ui.modules.core.widgets.editors.GlobalRefEditor$EditGlobalElementAction.findAndEditGlobal(GlobalRefEditor.java:772)
    at org.mule.tooling.ui.modules.core.widgets.editors.GlobalRefEditor$EditGlobalElementAction.run(GlobalRefEditor.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

Comment: Is this a Maven project? If so a dependency tree should provide insight. If it is a Studio project, share the build path.

Comment: updated question with build path and project platform

Comment: can you add the complete stack trace of the error?